# C++ Decrementing and displaying active equations

Tags: c++

I'm looking at figuring out this program for a lab, I have been working on it for a while now, but cannot for the life of me figure out how this works.

The objective is to display an active equation as it decrements from from the initial value.
For example:

```
20000.00 + 83.33 - 150.00 = 19933.33
19933.33 + 83.06 - 150.00 = 19866.39
19866.39 + 82.78 - 150.00 = 19799.17
19799.17 + 82.50 - 150.00 = 19731.66
19731.66 + 82.22 - 150.00 = 19663.88
19663.88 + 81.93 - 150.00 = 19595.81
19595.81 + 81.65 - 150.00 = 19527.46
```

And so forth. I have to display that as an output on the screen. But am not sure how to keep a decrementing total like that and how to display it as an active equation like that in cout form.

The number on the far left is an initial loan that a user inputs, the number in the middle is the interest rate which is calculate using p*r/p (initial loan * interestrate(user will input this as well)/ initial loan). And the number on the right just before the equal sign is a payment which the usual will enter.

The goal is to get it to perform 10 iterations or once the initial loan is fully paid off whichever comes first.

Comment: ***But am not sure how to keep a decrementing total like that*** Its just a double variable. ***how to display it as an active equation like that in cout form*** Use cout to print the values and symbols. There is nothing at all complicated with this.

Comment: ***The goal is to get it to perform 10 iterations or once the initial loan is fully paid off whichever comes first.*** Use a loop. Check the remaining in the loop..

Comment: @drescherjm I mean like I know its a double variable and to use cout to print it. But how would that be done in a loop as the directions say. I'm not allowed to manually cout 10 lines of of code.

Comment: The equation for the interest rate seems to be wrong: `p*r/p` gives `r` if `p != 0`. Give me a better task description and I will give you a solution.

Comment: My apologies it is p*r/1200. And the objective of the task is to use the inputs given by the user and to implement them into a do while loop and to display on the screen something an equation like that which decrements the numbers in that fashion, as well as the symbols and everything. (The numbers might look different depending what the user inputs).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a little guidance

## Finance

First you got your basics wrong. If this is finance and it looks this way :-), p*r/p is crap.
The second column in your plot is not a rate, neither is it an interest rate, it is an interest.

P is the loan ammount
r is an annual interest rate

The interest is calculated using P times r/12 since the payments you show are monthly in case r is entered mathematically (e.g. 0.05 for 5 %) or P*r/1200 in case r is counterconventional entered as percentage.

## C++

The input of the parameters could be done e.g.

```
double P, r, q;
std::cout << "Enter P, q and r:\t";
std::cin >> P >> r >> q;
```

you will need to have the numbers printed fixed precision, this can by done with

```
std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2)
```

one last hint: The needed include files will be

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
```

last you will need a loop have a look for for-loops or do-while loops.

This should help you to get your homework a good start.

Comment: Thank you so much man! I'll give this a try and let you know how it goes!